# How does the collectAsMap() function work for Spark API

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to understand as to what happens when we run the `collectAsMap`() function in spark. As per the Pyspark docs,it says,

> collectAsMap(self)
>   Return the key-value pairs in this RDD to the master as a dictionary.

and for core spark it says,

> def collectAsMap(): Map[K, V] Return the key-value pairs in this RDD
>   to the master as a Map.

When I try to run a sample code in pyspark for a List, I get this result:
[image: pyspark result]

and for scala  I get this result:
[image: scala result]

I am a little confused as to why it is not returning all the elements in the List. Can somebody help me understand what is happening in this scenario as to why I am getting selective results.

Thanks.

Comment: when you *collect* the RDD as a map/dictionary, it can't use the same key for multiple, distinct key-value pairs and thus each successive pair with the same key overwrites that before it. thus only the last two pairs in each of your two examples survive in `collectAsMap`. you'll see all of the original pairs are preserved in an array or list if you simply use `collect`

Comment: Thanks @oldrinb That clears my doubt about collectAsMap. :)

Answer (score 4):

The semantics of `collectAsMap` are identical between the Scala and Python APIs so I'll look at the first WLOG. The documentation for [`PairRDDFunctions.collectAsMap`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions@collectAsMap():Map[K,V]) explicitly states:

> Warning: this doesn't return a multimap (so if you have multiple values to the same key, only one value per key is preserved in the map returned)

In particular, the current implementation inserts the key-value pairs into the resultant map in order and thus only the last two pairs survive in each of your two examples.

If you use `collect` instead, it will return `Array[(Int,Int)]` without losing any of your pairs.

Answer (score 1):

`collectAsMap` will return the results for paired `RDD` as Map collection. And since it is returning Map collection you will only get pairs with unique keys and pairs with duplicate keys will be removed.