# Spark DataFrame to Dict - dictionary update sequence element error

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, dictionary, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to convert the `DataFrame` as Dict using `collectAsMap()` function in `RDD`.

**Code:**

```
dict = df.rdd.collectAsMap()
```

**Error log:**

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 8; 2 is required
```

**Update:**

The DF has 8 fields, does it mean the `collectAsMap()` can be used only DF with two fields?

Answer (score 5):

below is an explanation to do same thing in pyspark. I agree with Ram explanation.
collectAsMap is only applicable to pairedrdd so you need to convert your dataframe to pair rdd first and then can convert it into some dictionary using collectAsMap function.

For example, I have a below dataframe:

```
df = spark.sql("""select emp_id,emp_city from udb.temptable_1 order by emp_id""");
+------+--------+
|emp_id|emp_city|
+------+--------+
|     1|NOIDA   |
|     2|GURGAON |
|     3|DWARKA  |
|     4|SAKET   |
|     5|USA     |
|     6|UP      |
|     7|NOIDA   |
|     8|SAKET   |
|     9|GURGAON |
+------+--------+
```

## converting it into a key value pair rdd

```
newrdd = df.rdd.map(lambda x : (x[0],x))

>>> type(newrdd)
<class 'pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD'>

[(1, Row(emp_id=1, emp_city=u'NOIDA   ')), 
(2, Row(emp_id=2, emp_city=u'GURGAON ')), 
(3, Row(emp_id=3, emp_city=u'DWARKA  ')), 
(4, Row(emp_id=4, emp_city=u'SAKET   ')), 
(5, Row(emp_id=5, emp_city=u'USA     ')), 
(6, Row(emp_id=6, emp_city=u'UP      ')), 
(7, Row(emp_id=7, emp_city=u'NOIDA   ')), 
(8, Row(emp_id=8, emp_city=u'SAKET   ')), 
(9, Row(emp_id=9, emp_city=u'GURGAON '))]
```

finally you can use collectAsMap to convert your key-value pair rdd into a dict

```
dict = newrdd.collectAsMap()

{1: Row(emp_id=1, emp_city=u'NOIDA   '), 
2: Row(emp_id=2, emp_city=u'GURGAON '), 
3: Row(emp_id=3, emp_city=u'DWARKA  '), 
4: Row(emp_id=4, emp_city=u'SAKET   '), 
5: Row(emp_id=5, emp_city=u'USA     '), 
6: Row(emp_id=6, emp_city=u'UP      '), 
7: Row(emp_id=7, emp_city=u'NOIDA   '), 
8: Row(emp_id=8, emp_city=u'SAKET   '), 
9: Row(emp_id=9, emp_city=u'GURGAON ')}

>>> dict.keys()
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

>>> dict.get(2)
Row(emp_id=2, emp_city=u'GURGAON ')
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing I am bad in python/pyspark so I demoed using scala...

> `collectAsMap` is only applicable for pairedRDD (see below code from
>   spark [doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.collectAsMap)/code base)

```
/**
       * Return the key-value pairs in this RDD to the master as a Map.
       *
       * Warning: this doesn't return a multimap (so if you have multiple values to the same key, only
       *          one value per key is preserved in the map returned)
       *
       * @note this method should only be used if the resulting data is expected to be small, as
       * all the data is loaded into the driver's memory.
       */
      def collectAsMap(): Map[K, V] = self.withScope {
        val data = self.collect()
        val map = new mutable.HashMap[K, V]
        map.sizeHint(data.length)
        data.foreach { pair => map.put(pair._1, pair._2) }
        map
      }
```

your `df.rdd` is equivalent to `RDD[Row]` since you are converting `DataFrame` in to `RDD`.

so you can * NOT* collect it as a map. unless you have to do a `keyBy` (**Creates tuples of the elements in this RDD by applying `f`**) any element in the row to that. or some other operation which will convert that in to paired RDD.

Below is the complete example to demonstrate that.

---

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.internal.Logging
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

/** *
  * collectAsMap is only applicable to pairedrdd if you want to do a map then you can do a rdd key by and proceed
  *
  * @author : Ram Ghadiyaram
  */
object PairedRDDPlay extends Logging {
  Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
  // Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val appName = if (args.length > 0) args(0) else this.getClass.getName
    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder
      .config("spark.master", "local") //.config("spark.eventLog.enabled", "true")
      .appName(appName)
      .getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    val pairs = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Array((1, 1,3), (1, 2,3), (1, 3,3), (1, 1,3), (2, 1,3))).toDF("mycol1", "mycol2","mycol3")
    pairs.show()

    val keyedBy = pairs.rdd.keyBy(_.getAs[Int]("mycol1"))
    keyedBy.foreach(x => println("using keyBy-->>" + x))
    val myMap = keyedBy.collectAsMap()
    println(myMap.toString())
    assert(myMap.size == 2)
    //    val myMap1 = pairs.rdd.collectAsMap()
    //    println(myMap1.toString())
    //    assert(myMap1.size == 2)
    //Error:(28, 28) value collectAsMap is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
    //    val myMap1 = pairs.rdd.collectAsMap()
  }
}
```

***Result :***

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
+------+------+------+
|mycol1|mycol2|mycol3|
+------+------+------+
|     1|     1|     3|
|     1|     2|     3|
|     1|     3|     3|
|     1|     1|     3|
|     2|     1|     3|
+------+------+------+

using keyBy-->>(1,[1,1,3])
using keyBy-->>(1,[1,2,3])
using keyBy-->>(1,[1,3,3])
using keyBy-->>(1,[1,1,3])
using keyBy-->>(2,[2,1,3])
Map(2 -> [2,1,3], 1 -> [1,1,3])
```

> Question : The DF has 8 fields, does it mean the `collectAsMap`() can be used
>   only DF with two fields?

---

Answer : NO you can see the example with multiple columns (i.e. >2) in the example. but you need to convert it to pairrdd.

Also have a look at [how-does-the-collectasmap-function-work-for-spark-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37734398/how-does-the-collectasmap-function-work-for-spark-api)

Comment: is it helping you ?